# Can you use Android Studio for Samsung Gear 2?

Tags: samsung-mobile, tizen-wearable-sdk

I have an app that I would like to build wearable support across platforms. I got Android Wear support, I got Gear Fit support. Now I am trying to figure out the Tizen SDK and if I can integrate that with Android Studio. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't say it's not possible, but Android Studio/IntelliJ does not support the Tizen Wearable build process at this time. I don't know what the long-term plans are for the Tizen SDK team--if whether they will continue with Eclipse as it is or start providing support for A/S themselves.

A Tizen Wearable app is for all intents and purposes a web app with a few config.xml changes and some custom folders, so there may be a way to cobble support in if you were really desperate enough.  Behind the scenes, [here is what the Tizen IDE/Eclipse is doing](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/ide_sdk_tools/command_line_interface.htm). Perhaps this will give you enough of a start.

edit: rearranged for clarity